# Symfony&Doctrine Foreign Key reference

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, symfony

I have problem with foreign key.

Logs

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: "Expected value of type "GuideBundle\Entity\Actors" for association field "GuideBundle\Entity\MedicalStaff#$actorId", got "integer" instead." at D:\Elya\КПИ\6 семестр\TSPP\mg\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException.php line 206  []
```

MedicalStaff Entity

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Actors")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="actorId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $actorId;
```

Actors Entity

```
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
```

MedicalStaffController

```
/**
     * Creates a new MedicalStaff entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="admin_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $medicalStaff = new MedicalStaff();
        $actor = new Actors();
        $form = $this->createForm('GuideBundle\Form\MedicalStaffType', $medicalStaff);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $actor->setRole(2);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($actor);
            $em->flush();
            $medicalStaff->setActorId($actor->getId()); //problem
            $em->persist($medicalStaff); //is
            $em->flush(); //here
            //$this->generateLogin($medicalStaff->getActorId(), $medicalStaff->getEmail());
            $flash = $this->get('braincrafted_bootstrap.flash');
            $flash->success('Succesfully registered.');
        }
        return $this->render('medicalstaff/new.html.twig', array(
            'medicalStaff' => $medicalStaff,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

Maybe I use FK reference not correctly. I need to set MedicalStaff.actorId the same as Actor.id, that was inserted above

Comment: With Doctrine you are working with the actual entities themselves, not the foreign keys. `$actorId` should be `$actor`, and `$medicalStaff->setActorId($actor->getId());` should be `$medicalStaff->setActor($actor);`. Or just to get it working as is `$medicalStaff->setActorId($actor);` though I highly suggest fixing the naming

Comment: @JimL but I don't understand how this actor will be stored in database, what type should I set for actor?

Comment: @JimL Thank you very much! I have tried `$medicalStaff->setActorId($actor);` before, but it didn't work, now I understand why, and everything is fine.

Comment: Yes Doctrine automatically takes the actors ID (if that is the FK) and handles that for you. That said you can probably as well see why it makes sense to change the name to `$actor` and method name to `setActor`, as you're not yourself handling the IDs

Comment: @JimL could you help me with another problem please? Now I need to delete MedicalStaff object with an Actor (from Actors entity), that it referenced. `onDelete="cascade");` deletes actor.id, which equals MedicalStaff.id; but I need to delete an actor, that is storing in MedicalStaff.actor. How can I do this?